Confidence Interval for Expected Value of Binomial Distribution
been trying to wrap my head around this for a while. What is the confidence interval for the expected value for a binomial distribution?
Let's say for a sample, I throw a coin 7 times and only 1 is landed on heads (k=1, n=7). Using a GC, my unbiased estimate for population mean (ie sample mean) is 0.14285 and unbiased estimate for population variance is 0.142857.
Is it accurate to assume the confidence interval would follow the same formula of other confidence intervals?
$$ z1⋅\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}} $$
hence
$$ z1⋅\sqrt{\frac{0.142857}{{n}}} $$

On another note, I came across the equations of n(p)(1-p) for calculating the variance of binomial distribution. However, when I inputted the variables of p = 1/7 and n = 7 (as with the example above) into the equation, the output was not the same as the sample variance or unbiased estimate for population variance calculated by the GC.
Why is there a difference between the two?

It appears your GC is using the formula
$$\left(\dfrac{n}{n-1}\right)\overline{p}\left(1-\overline{p}\right)$$
for its unbiased estimator of the variance.  The simpler alternative,
$$\overline{p}\left(1-\overline{p}\right),$$
is actually biased.
When constructing confidence intervals for the Bernoulli proportion, $p$, one generally proceeds in much the same way as with other confidence intervals based on the Normal approximation.  However, it is common to use the biased estimator of the variance,
$$\overline{p}\left(1-\overline{p}\right),$$
both because it is simpler to remember and because inserting the unbiased estimator technically would require using t-scores rather than z-scores -- an unnecessary complication.
